# Make layout width equal height?

Tags: android

I want to have an ImageView with width=fill_parent, and the height should be whatever the width is. I'm not sure if there's a way to specify that in xml, is the only option to create my own ImageView-derived class?:

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

    // Just return whatever the current width is?
    private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
        return getWidth();
    }
}
```

Is this the way to go, any other options? (I'm not sure if the above is even correct, not sure if the width measurement even takes place before the height measurement for example)

Thanks

Comment: If you set your width to fill_parent, the method getWidth() will return 0. this approach will not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the width with the method

```
imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
```

So, you can set it's height

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), imageView.getMeasuredWidth()));
```

Comment: Where exactly would you set this in the layout pass (ie: which method)?

Answer (score 0):

### Make layout height equal to the width:

The problem with [digulino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10263269/1533054) (in my case at least) is that if you want to change the dimensions in the start, `getMeasuredWidth()` will return `0` because the views haven't been drawn yet.

You can still do it by using a `Runnable()` thread like this:

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.myFrame);
frame.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams;
        lparams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) frame.getLayoutParams();
        lparams.height = frame.getWidth();
        frame.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        frame.postInvalidate();
    }
});
```

***Important Note:***
*This example assumes your view is a `FrameLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Change it accordingly for other layouts.*

Comment: This won't work if width is set to for example "match_parent" (-1). It will work only if you previously numerically specified Width for that layout.

Comment: Fine, so you previously specified the layout width. But it won't work in the other cases (and I just tested it).